Customise SharePoint Online pages
Using SharePoint online I'm looking at creating several customised page layouts for differing content.
The idea is the user can select the type of page to create (like a template with placeholders), when the page is created, it allows the user to add content within pre-defined areas.
This has the advantage of ensuring the correct metadata and content is collected.
The important thing is that the user cannot change the layout, but only add content in a structured manner. Then they submit for approval.
I've looked at creating page and templates but cannot lock the areas, nor is the page intelligent to detect missing areas of data.
The advantage of a page is that its searchable and can be bookmarked, so not keen on PowerApps.
Thanks

Yes, you can create "page templates" for fixed layouts BUT you cannot lock it as user with edit access can make any changes to the newly created page (using template).

There needs to be a way to lock templates, from general contributors. I wont be able to produce a solution without it. Years ago, we could use SPD to create placeholders, is there no such thing anylonger.

I don't think there are any similar SharePoint out of the box options available in "modern" experience.

What are the custom options (i.e. development) ?
